# What is "%TEMP%\Encoding Time.csv" on Windows?

Tags: malware

Does anyone know what app is writing to file "%TEMP%\Encoding Time.csv"? The file is constantly growing. Searching Internet did not yield any meaningful results. Below is an example of the records in the file.

> 0x1B959F08, 37033756854966440, 11792153, 11792156, 3, 640x360
>
> 0x1B959F08, 37033756855766744, 11792232, 11792236, 4, 640x360
>
> 0x1B959F08, 37033756856405856, 11792303, 11792306, 3, 640x360

Comment: I did trace it to Skype. In my case it wasn't even running. But would autostart and run for about 20 secs and then close. I have no idea what it was doing or why it needed to write this strange file. Smells fishy to me

Comment: I've this file created sometimes in C:\Temp

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have also come across this file, I discovered it is created by Skype for Business by deleting the file and having it re-create during a skype video meeting. I'm not sure why it is created or how to disable it though.

Comment: Skype (not Skype for Business) can create it too in C:\Temp.

Comment: Skype have been uninstalled from my laptop and this file is still created there. It comes from Microsoft Teams.

Answer (score 9):

Seems like Microsoft Teams can create this too (since the video conference is based on Skype).  This showed up for me after I set a custom background. 
Sample line:

> 0x0000024088504A10, 37960914834869640, 204351, 204361, 10, 1920x1080

The last column is the dimensions of the background image.

Comment: I just noticed this today, sounds like a debug file from developers to create it if you have a temp folder on C

Comment: I've also this file created in c:\temp and I've Teams on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

The "Encoding Time.csv" is created by Skype and/or Microsoft Teams. It appears to be some kind of debug information for video/screen rendering.

It is safe to delete manually, or can also be removed during Disk Cleanup if "Temporary Files" is checked.